# how to get list view reference in code .....that is inside Listview Resource

Tags: wpf, listview

how to get list view reference in code .....that is inside Listview Resource

Answer (score 2):

Slightly confusing question, but...

You might use [FrameworkElement.FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx):

```
object resource = myListView.FindResource("resourceName");
```